# Reconstructing a matrix with complex elements after diagonalization

Tags: python, scipy, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I have a random matrix `Htest` with complex elements, which I diagonalize using `scipy.linalg.eig`. Having the decomposed matrices, I tried to reconstruct the original matrix. Here is my script

```
    import numpy as np
    import scipy as sp
    import random
    
    L0=4
    Htest= np.array([[random.random()+1j*random.random() for e in range(L0)] for e in range(L0)])
    
    # calculate spin energy levels
    E, Vl, Vr=sp.linalg.eig(Htest,left=True)#
    E=np.array(E)
    Vl=np.array(Vl)
    Vr=np.array(Vr)
    idx = E.argsort()[::1]#sort with smallest eigenvalues
    Es = E[idx]
    Vrs = Vr[:,idx]
    Vls = Vl[:,idx]
    
    # This should be a null matrix, but it is not!
    print(np.round( (Htest)-  Vls.T.conj() @ np.diag(Es) @Vrs ,3))
    
    #This works
    for i in  range(L0):
        print(np.round( np.dot(Htest  , Vrs[:,i] )- Es[i] * Vrs[:,i] ,3))
        print(np.round( np.dot(Htest.conj().T, Vls[:,i] )- Es[i].conj() * Vls[:,i],3))
```

Do you have any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: Could you provide a reference for this claim? `Vls.T.conj() @ np.diag(Es) @Vrs`

Answer (score 0):

Making your (4,4) complex array with `np.random.rand`.

```
In [85]: Htest = np.random.rand(L0,L0)+np.random.rand(L0,L0)*1j
```

And the decomposition:

```
In [86]: E, Vl, Vr=linalg.eig(Htest,left=True)
In [87]: E.shape, Vl.shape, Vr.shape
Out[87]: ((4,), (4, 4), (4, 4))
```

The outputs are already arrays.  And testing without sorting.

```
In [88]: np.allclose(Htest@Vr, E*Vr)
Out[88]: True
In [89]: np.allclose(Htest.conj().T@Vl, E.conj() * Vl)
Out[89]: True
```

With `svd:

```
In [127]: U, s, Vh = linalg.svd(Htest)
In [130]: np.allclose(Htest, U@np.diag(s)@Vh)
Out[130]: True
```

I don't remember enough linalg to correct this (yet)

```
In [137]: np.allclose(Htest, Vl.T.conj() @ np.diag(E) @Vr)
Out[137]: False
```

And alternative to using `diag`:

```
In [152]: np.allclose(E[:,None]*Vl, np.diag(E)@Vl)
Out[152]: True
```

I don't know if this is useful or not.

A general web search about recreating a matrix from eigenvalues and eigenvectors turns up a number StackExchange questions, some SO, some Math.  There seem to be constraints on that (symmetric?).  You may need to supply a math reference.

### edit

```
In [173]: np.allclose(Htest, Vr@np.diag(E)@np.linalg.inv(Vr))
Out[173]: True

In [176]: np.allclose(Htest, Vr@(E[:,None]*np.linalg.inv(Vr)))
Out[176]: True
```

From the earlier test:

```
Htest@Vr == E*Vr
Htest@Vr == Vr*E
Htest@Vr == Vr@diag(E)
Htest@Vr@inv(Vr) == Vr@diag(E)@inv(Vr)
Htest == Vr@diag(E)@inv(Vr)
```

By the same logic for `Vl`:

```
In [201]: np.allclose(Htest.conj().T, (Vl*E.conj())@np.linalg.inv(Vl))
Out[201]: True
In [203]: np.allclose(Htest.conj().T, Vl@np.diag(E.conj())@np.linalg.inv(Vl))
Out[203]: True
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I have found the correct transformation, which is`Vrs @ np.diag(Es) @np.linalg.inv(Vrs) `. If you could incorporate this into your answer, the problem is solved, and I can accept it so that others benefit from that.